# Count white pixels from 'multiple images' in python

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel, mask

I'm trying to calculate the sum of white pixels in multiple images.

I am able to count the number of white pixels in one image ([2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyysf.png) )with this code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray)
print('pixel count', pixels)
```

, but I don't know how to do it with multiple images. 
I would like to input multiple images and get the sum of all the white pixels.
I'm fairly new to python and need some help with this.
Thank you!

Comment: Hello @jennifer, please provide an example of what you tried and a more specific question

Comment: @NicolòGasparini Hello, thank you for the response. Sorry that my question wasn't more specific. I edited the question with images and code, and I hope it's clearer now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already achieved the hard part (that was reading the number of white pixels, what you want to do is a simple [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing), since you have multiple images, that's the list of elements you will be iterating, something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
counter = 0
for img_path in ['2.png', '3.png', '4.png']:  # all of your images
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray)
    counter += pixels  # Keeping track ot the *total* number of pixels

print('total pixel count', counter)
```

Comment: Thank you @Nicolò Gasparini ! I was wondering if I can read the images by a file path ex. D:\folder, since I have around 50~60 images to process. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes you can, here you can find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory